# counterexample for a theorem in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In our class we have shown that
if a set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is  *measurable* than for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ an open set $O$, containing $F$, such that $\mu^*(O - F) \leq \epsilon$
My question is how can I have a counter example if the set is not measurable? I should prove that it does not exist an open set such that the last property $\mu^*(O - F) \leq \epsilon$ is not valid?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure

Comment: Try to show that if such a set exists for every epsilon, then the set is measurable.

Comment: It will be hard to explicitly work out a counterexample, because constructing non-measurable sets needs the axiom of choice, which makes these examples very non-explicit...

Comment: @Lukas it depdns on the $\sigma $-algebra. By example if we assume the Borel $\sigma $-algebra instead of the Lebesgue $\sigma $-algebra then there are non-measurable Lebesgue sets. Its true that they are hard to construct but not as harder as non Lebesgue measurable sets. The question lacks seriously of context and details.

Comment: @Masacroso: Sure, it could be some arbitrary measure on some arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra, but do you honestly think this was not about Lebesgue measure? I am all for nitpicking, but sometimes it makes more sense to work with implicit assumptions... (E.g., for the trivial $\sigma$-algebra consisting only of the empty set and the whole space, non-measurable sets are easy to construct, but this is obviously not a question about general measures.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting theorem, without some restriction, is false as it depends entirely in the measure. By example if $\mu$ is the counting measure then for every nonempty open set $O\subset \mathbb{R}$ you have that $\mu^*(O\setminus \{0\})=\infty $.

P.S.: I'm assuming here that $\mu^*$ is induced from $\mu$ and the collection of open sets.